# backbone App is not defined error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, backbone.js

I've been following the cloudedit tutorial http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/01/27/cloudedit-a-backbone-js-tutorial-by-example/ for adding backbone to my rails app, but I'm using rails 3.1.3 rather than 3.0.

I keep getting the following errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined
application.js:7Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I believe the error is caused by the following code

```
var App = {
    Views: {},
    Controllers: {},
    Collections: {},
    init: function() {
        new App.Controllers.Recipes();
        Backbone.history.start();
    }
};
```

which is pretty much right from the tutorial. 
I currently have this code in

```
assets/javascripts/application.js
```

file, underneath the section where I include the directories, and I call

```
        $(function(){
        App.init();
           });
```

in my application.html.erb file.

the line which the error is actually referring to is

```
App.Controllers.Recipes = Backbone.Controller.extend(
```

I've tried moving the var App around to different files, but i can't seem to get it to work.

Am I understanding that error correctly? Is there something else I may be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a version of Backbone >= `0.5.0` if so there is no `Controller` object anymore. It's been renamed to `Router`.